# Vue.js component data variable undefined in method

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I have something like this as a component:

```
Vue.component
(
    'mycomp',
    {
        props : ['c'],
        data : function()
        {
            return { var1 : true, var2 : [] }
        },
        template : `<div v-html='func1(c.id)'></div>`,
        methods :
        {
            func1(id)
            {
                // ...
                return func2(id);
            },
            func2(id)
            {
                var someRegExp = /blah/ig;
                return id.replace(someRegExp, function(capture)
                {
                   //...
                   if(cond) this.var2.push(id);
                   return `<a href='/post/${id}'></a>`
                });
            }
        }
     }
  );
```

The error I get here would be:

`TypeError: "this.var2 is undefined"` and the source of the error points to `func2`. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `this` refers to the `replace` functions context, not vues method context

change it like this

```
return id.replace(someRegExp, (capture) => {
    //...
    if(cond) this.var2.push(id);
    return `<a href='/post/${id}'></a>`
});
```

So that the context is bound properly.  Or alternatively, do this

```
const self=this;
return id.replace(someRegExp, function (capture) {
    //...
    if(cond) self.var2.push(id);
    return `<a href='/post/${id}'></a>`
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll accept it as answer after the minimum time limit. My application hangs after fixing this line, clearly for some other problem, is there anything obvious that you notice from what I posted that might be causing the problem ?

Comment: @RobertC.Holland I don't see anything obvious in it.  Can you post a fiddle or something of the problem?  I would probably have used a computed, not a function for this. Even a custom filter that applies the regex would work

Comment: It was related to using method instead of computed, it has been resolved, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ES6's *arrow functions*, where the `this` pointer will retain the context of the parent.

```
return id.replace(someRegExp, (capture) => {
    //...
    if(cond) this.var2.push(id);
    return `<a href='/post/${id}'></a>`
});
```